# Bloquear páginas com login no AngularJS com chamada assíncrona

Tags: angularjs

Em uma aplicação feita com AngularJS, algumas páginas são protegidas por login.

Configurei o módulo da seguinte forma:

```
var app = angular.module('App', ['ngRoute', 'ngTouch', 'mobile-angular-ui']);

app.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        //...
        .when('/dashboard', {
            title: 'Dashboard',
            templateUrl: 'view/dashboard.html',
            controller: 'authCtrl',
            requireLogin: true
        })
        //...
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}])
.run(function ($rootScope, $route, $location, Data, Session) {        
    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event) {
        var nextPath = $location.path();
        var nextRoute = $route.routes[nextPath];
        if (nextRoute.requireLogin && !Session.getUserAuthenticated()) {
           $location.path("/login");
        }
    });
});
```

Repare que no fim do código acima, tenho um service (Session.getUserAuthenticated()) que faz a verificação se o utilizador fez login antes de mudar a rota, veja o código:

```
app.service('Session', function($http) {
    this.getUserAuthenticated = function() {
        var auth = false;
        $http.post('api/v1/session').then(function (results) {
            if(results.data.uid) auth = true;
        });
        return auth;
    };
});
```

O problema é que o serviço acima retorna sempre false, uma vez que faz o return antes da resposta do $http.post, como resolvo o problema? É possível esperar pela resposta do POST ou a lógica que estou a usar é incorrecta?

Comment: Passe um callback para a o serviço. Mas o mais recomendado acredito que seja não enviar as partes que só devem ser acessadas quando autenticado.

Comment: Na verdade você está retornando auth false pois ele é retornado antes do POST ocorrer. O post é assíncrono. Neste caso deves trabalhar com CallBack ou Promisses para só retornar se está autorizado dentro do resultado do POST

Comment: @Caputo como seria isso? Teria que remover esse service ou altera-lo? Obrigado.

Comment: @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira esses bloqueio é só no frontend, no servidor também faço a verificação, isso seria apenas para evitar requests desnecessários. Mas como seria o recomendado? obrigado.

Comment: Estou meio corrido aqui, não sei como está seu inglês, mas dê uma olhada nessa resposta e no link dela http://stackoverflow.com/a/16627409/3590714

Answer (score 1):

Não testei, mas seria algo próximo a isso (já te dá um bom início):

```
app.service('Session', function($http) {
    this.getUserAuthenticated = function() {
        return $http.post('api/v1/session');
    };
});
```

E a verificação algo assim:

```
.run(function ($rootScope, $route, $location, Data, Session) {
    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event) {
        var nextPath = $location.path();
        var nextRoute = $route.routes[nextPath];
        if (nextRoute.requireLogin) {
            Session.getUserAuthenticated().success(function(results) {
                if (results.data.uid) console.log('autorizado!');
                else $location.path("/login");
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Eu resolvi isso utilizando o "Resolve", porém ainda não consegui resolver alguns problemas para postar uma resposta completa, mas obrigado.

Comment: Pelo menos a resposta é útil?